# Where to find the driver for Epson WorkForce WF-2860 under Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic?

Tags: drivers, 18.04, scanner, epson

I cannot scan with the Epson WorkForce WF-2860 under Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic. The scanner is plugged in per USB and still the Utsushi scan program is unable to detect the scanner. Does someone know where to find the correct drivers and can give the instructions to install it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know where to find the scanner driver.

It is here https://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/?OSC=LX

You could easily find it too by googling "epson linux drivers".

Comment: I have been there but failed to install the "All-in-one package" due to some dependencies on pipelight that is not supported for Ubuntu 18.04 and end up at `E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/pipelight/stable/ubuntu/dists/bionic/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found`

Comment: This is not related to the drivers. pipelight is obsolete. Remove this ppa. But this error doesn't stop installing everything else.

Answer (score 0):

Visit the Official Ubuntu documentation [SANE - Scanner Access Now Easy](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/sane).
It may be necessary to also install the sane packages listed on that page for functioning if you haven't already.

Attempt to detect scanner in a terminal with:

`scanimage -L`

`sane-find-scanner`

I would also suggest launching the epson `imagescan` utility from a terminal so you can see any output to the terminal that may give you more information.

A look through the Imagescan [source](http://support.epson.net/linux/src/scanner/imagescanv3/ubuntu/) files can give you clues to other packages that may be needed for functionality.

[imagescan_3.62.0-1epson4ubuntu18.04.debian.tar.xz](http://support.epson.net/linux/src/scanner/imagescanv3/ubuntu/imagescan_3.62.0-1epson4ubuntu18.04.debian.tar.xz)

[imagescan_3.62.0-1epson4ubuntu18.04.dsc](http://support.epson.net/linux/src/scanner/imagescanv3/ubuntu/imagescan_3.62.0-1epson4ubuntu18.04.dsc)

Another GUI utility that may be of use is Simple-Scan.

`sudo apt install simple-scan`

Here is a link to another site that may provide some more information.

[A Scanner How-To for Epson Scanners](http://www.subdude-site.com/WebPages_Local/RefInfo/Computer/Linux/ScannerHowTo/Scanner_HowTo_forEpson.htm)